# Merge duplicate rows and populate new columns with duplicate data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, duplicates

Newbie to SQL here and need a bit of guidance. Any would be appreciated!

So say I have a SQL table as follows:

```
id  email            preference
1   john@gmail.com   cake
1   john@gmail.com   fruit
1   john@gmail.com   cheese
1   john@gmail.com   sauce
2   mark@gmail.com   cake
2   mark@gmail.com   sauce
3   kate@gmail.com   tea
```

What I want to do is merge the duplicate records (based on id and email), but also use the duplicate data in the "preferences" column to populate some additional columns in a new table. Basically I want to get to this:

```
id  email           preference1   preference2   preference3   preference4 
1   john@gmail.com  cake          fruit         cheese        sauce
2   mark@gmail.com  cake          sauce         null          null
2   kate@gmail.com  tea           null          null          null
```

Currently at a bit of a loss of how to get here.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Have you considered another table with a different structure like (id, person_id, preference)? This can allow you to see all the preferences of an individual and respect 2nd Normal Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you have four preferences, you can use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select id, email,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then preference end) as preference_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then preference end) as preference_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then preference end) as preference_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then preference end) as preference_4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, email order by preference) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, email;
```